# Where can I find RxJS application design / architecture resources

Tags: web-applications, architecture, rxjs

I have been learning RxJS for a while now and while I have plenty of api documentation and working examples of its usage, I am at the stage where I would like to start building some applications with it.

The problem is, no matter how I try, I can't seem to find any online resources discussing architecture and design decisions for applications using RxJS.

Things like, should I use RxJS in with a flux system (redux) or just on its own, or is this a situational decision?
Also like if I'm making a small turn based card game, should I have a circular loop of streams running it, or should there be external code i.e 'new game' functionality that creates new streams as a starting point each time, etc.

Basically the ideas behind using RxJS in actual projects, high level architecture decisions and philosophies.

Does anyone know of some decent resources for this sort of thing.

Just to be clear, I do not want api documentation or documentation explaining what RxJS is or how it works, that is not the information I'm looking for.

Comment: If you just started with RxJs I would not recommend building your own state management system, unless its very simple or if you have lots of free time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that this kind of information is quite decentralized and spread out across lots of blogs, platforms, podcasts etc... [Medium](https://medium.com/) is also a good place to find this type of information. A lot of the time it is discussed in the context of a framework, eg:

- https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngrx-store-and-effects-crash-course/
- https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-redux-architecture-part-1-separation-of-concerns-812da3b08b46
- https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-rxjs-state-management-tutorial/

My personal opinion on what you are trying to do is that you have 2 options:

1. If you are using a framework such as React/Angular, use a state management library, eg. Redux, NgRx.
2. Implement your own State management solution using Behaviour Subjects. How to do this with Angular and RxJS is [explained here](https://medium.com/@rmcavin/my-favorite-state-management-technique-in-angular-rxjs-behavior-subjects-49f18daa31a7). You could build something similar if you are using React or Vanilla JS rather than Angular.

> Things like, should I use RxJS in with a flux system (redux) or just
>   on its own, or is this a situational decision?

This is a situational decision - for larger applications I would use a state management library as it will scale better and allow for easier debugging via the [Redux DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en).

For a smaller application you can just use the Behaviour Subject solution mentioned above, this has the advantage of being a simpler solution involving less code and less mental overhead.

> Also like if I'm making a small turn based card game, should I have a
>   circular loop of streams running it, or should there be external code
>   i.e 'new game' functionality that creates new streams as a starting
>   point each time, etc.

In my opinion, the entire state of the application should be handled through whatever state management solution you choose. Eg. with redux, your 'new game' function would fire off 1 more more actions to reset the game state.

Comment: tx, I will check out this resources